# Is it better to spread out my satellites or concentrate them in one area?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Should I try to strengthen one area on the map to make travel times shorter or try to cover as much of the globe as possible?

Comment: What influence do additional satellites have on _travel_ times? They increase the likelihood of UFO detection and add income and boni, but travel time?

Comment: @zommuter well originally I thought the game would be like the original x-com, where you can only detect ufos when you have satellite coverage, so if you put a satellite on the opposite side of the globe your fighters won't be able to intercept without buying additional fighters for the base over there

Comment: That makes sense. Sigh, there's a lot of the original x-com I severely miss in the new one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that if you can do it without a country panicking and leaving the council, it's better to go ahead and fill a continent for the bonus.  However, in my limited experience I end up spending my satellites to calm down a nation more often than not.

Comment: note that you already have the bonus of your starting continent, so filling up a _different_ continent might be more suitable

Comment: This answer does not address the secondary question regarding whether it is beneficial to minimize travel time

Comment: --between your base and placed satellites.  First, it is worth noting that your satellite does not need to be in position before your council report to get financial credit; simply launching it will suffice.  Second, time spent traveling to and from UFO sites only seems to progress items in the Event List so you won't be missing other events; someone please correct me if I am wrong.  Regarding the second item, and assuming I am correct, it may be beneficial to launch distant satellites.  (Sorry for double comment; I accidentally submitted my comment unfinished.)

Comment: @bpcookson In how far _do_ additional satellites influence travel time at all? (PS: You can use shift+enter to add linebreaks in the text field, but they won't show up. Also you can edit old comments within five minutes)

Answer (score 5):

Covering a complete region with satellites gives you the continent bonus, same as if you had picked the region for XCOM HQ.

Unlike the bonus from your base, though, you can lose this if you lose full coverage for your satellites.

Comment: not to mention that you cannot obtain the bonus from a continent where a country has already withdrawn due to panic

Comment: @Zommuter All the more reason to focus on Panic reduction first, continent bonuses first.

Comment: @bpcookson There may be situations where you have to choose _either_ panic reduction _or_ obtaining a continent bonus. Since the eighth country backing out means game over, and a backed out country means no funds, panic reduction (once it reached five) should outweigh bonuses

Comment: @Zommuter Agreed.  I made a typo up there; meant to say continent bonuses come second.  And you imply a good point regarding when Panic reduction is critical: if it's _not_ at five and you're deploying satellites moments before your council report, that country can wait.

Comment: @bpcookson Yup, it may actually be beneficial to leave a country at five panic until short before the report, since that way one can consider saving another place should a negative event happen in multiple places - panic never exceeds five. One should however remember the entire continent's panic is influenced...

Answer (score 3):

I have found so far that you need some coverage on each continent to spot ufo's, otherwise they can terrorize continents undetected. I was playing on classic but trying to keep everyone happy, and still doing all the research, etc was impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that once a continent has been covered with satellites, it will no longer trigger alien abduction type missions, thus eliminating that continent from gaining additional panic levels due to you not picking a mission from that area.  This is very beneficial if that particular continent provides high income.  This also lets you funnel those missions to a particular continent, preferably one where you've already lost a country so you can't get the bonus anyway.